# Graph Not Drawing Values vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, graph, charts

```
    dtTest.Columns.Add("TestName", GetType(String))
    dtTest.Columns.Add("Score", GetType(Integer))

    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

    cn.Open()

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * From ScoreDB WHERE StudentName='" & SelectStudent.Text & "'", cn)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While (reader.Read())

        Dim TestName As String = Convert.ToString(reader("TestName"))

        Dim TestScore As String = Convert.ToString(reader("ScorePercentage"))

        GraphValues.Add(TestName, TestScore)

    End While

    Dim point As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)

    For Each point In GraphValues
        dtTest.Rows.Add(point.Key)
        dtTest.Rows.Add(point.Value)
        MsgBox(point.Key)
    Next

    With Chart1.ChartAreas(0)
        .AxisX.Minimum = 0
        .AxisX.Maximum = 10
        .AxisY.Minimum = 0
        .AxisY.Maximum = 100
        .AxisY.Interval = 10
        .AxisX.Title = "Test"
        .AxisY.Title = "Score Percentage"
    End With

    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

I've created a form that should output a the score and test name into a column chart in vb.net, It loads all the data from the database successfully but it fails to write it to the graph and ends up just like this

[image]

any help would be appreciated as I am really struggling with this at the moment and have searched various resources such as MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is telling the chart to map the datatable `GraphValues` to the chart. Try something like below. You may to tinker around with the code slightly

```
 Chart1.DataSource = GraphValues
 Chart1.Series(0).XValueMember = "TestName"
 Chart1.Series(0).YValueMembers = "Score"

 'Data bind to the selected data source
 Chart1.DataBind()
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx